# Erro retorno ajax ao enviar FormData com file para Controller MVC

Tags: ajax, json, mvc, controller, formdata

Estou com um problema que começou a ocorrer de uns tempos pra cá. Tenho uma view que envia um `FormData` com informações de anexos (input type file) para uma controller MVC através de um Ajax. A controller retorna um Json com algumas informações. Acontece que agora de uma hora pra outra está sendo retornado a view onde se encontra o ajax e não mais o Json da controller.

O estranho é que rodando local funciona. O problema só ocorre quando o sistema está hospedado.

Segue abaixo os códigos:

**View**

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('files');
var formData = new FormData();

for (i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
   formData.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);
}   

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../SistemaRelacionamento/SalvarAnexosRelacionamento",
  data: formData,
  dataType: 'json',                
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function (result) {
    alert(result);
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(" Status: " + textStatus + " Http error:" + errorThrown);     
}

});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SalvarAnexosRelacionamento()
{   
  try
  {
      List<int> idsAnexos = new List<int>();

      // Grava os anexos do relacionamento
      for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
      {
        if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/AnexoRelacionamentoFolder/")))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/AnexoRelacionamentoFolder/"));

        var novoNomeArquivo = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[i].FileName);
        var savedFileName = "\\GestorUnimed\\Uploads\\AnexoRelacionamentoFolder\\";
        savedFileName = Path.Combine(savedFileName, Path.GetFileName(novoNomeArquivo));

        var file = Request.Files[i];
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/AnexoRelacionamentoFolder/") + 
          Path.GetFileName(savedFileName));
        
        var idUltimoAnexo = PegaIdAnexo();

        idsAnexos.Add(idUltimoAnexo);
    }

    return Json(new { success = true, idAnexo = idsAnexos });                            
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return Json(new { success = false, idAnexo = 0 });
}
}
```

**Retorno**

[imagem do retorno com erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABobY.jpg)

Já pesquisei em tudo quanto é lugar e vi que nenhum código para envio do `FormData` para controller funcionou. Parece que parou de funcionar o `FormData` depois de hospedado o sistema.

Alguém pode dar uma luz?

Valeu pessoal

Comment: tem que colocar todo o erro na imagem, e você por acaso já debugou?

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).